# DocuSign Recipient sign url expire

Tags: docusignapi

I need to add DocuSign to my chat app (iOS, Android, Windows) in order to ask to sign documents to all the chat group members.

I want to implement DocuSign signing flow without Server implementation: only Sender and Recipients client side implementation (is it possible?).

Flow that I imagined:

- An authenticated Sender create the envelope with `Envelopes: create` REST call.
- Other members must sign the document (no DocuSign account needed)...
- ...so I need to generate a "recipient url" for every member using the REST call `EnvelopeViews: createRecipient` (who call this endpoint?)

I tested this flow with Postman and I've some questions:

1. `EnvelopeViews: createRecipient` require X-DocuSign-Authentication header, so this request must be called from Sender side, is it?
2. `EnvelopeViews: createRecipient` return an url that can be used once, why? The second time I use this url I get 404 as response.

So what I notice is the Recipient can't use the url (provided by the Sender) twice but he can't generate a new url every time because it isn't authenticated (no X-DocuSign-Authentication).

How can I implement this flow properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. X-DocuSign-Authentication header is legacy authentication, please don't use this as it's not as secure as modern OAauth.
2. Again, security. Every time you want someone to sign your code should generate the URL. Also, note you cannot generate two URLs. Only one is valid at a time. You need your app to have some logic to ensure that only one user is signing and only at that point in time the URL is generated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. About the second answer: are you telling me that only one user at time can sign the document? Can members sign at the same time?

Comment: one at a time. The envelope gets locked when someone signs. It's like an entry in a database, you cannot have two updates done at the same time.

Comment: if this answered your question - please mark it as answered.

Comment: I tried to sign a document with two signers at the same time and it works, at the end of the process I get the document updated with both signatures.

Comment: "at the same time" means simultaneously, not one after the other. Even if one is a second after the other - that's ok. How did you do that?

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks!
I created the signing URL for 2 users and I opened it at the same time on 2 different browsers...than I signed the document with some seconds of delay.

Comment: ok, if the original question is answered - would you mind marking it as answered?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good questions:

> EnvelopeViews: createRecipient require X-DocuSign-Authentication header, so this request must be called from Sender side, is it?

1. Do not use the `X-DocuSign-Authentication` header. That's "legacy authentication" and DocuSign does not support it for new REST eSignature apps. Instead, use OAuth. Probably the OAuth JWT grant flow since that flow enables your application to *impersonate* a DocuSign user (such as the sender), when the user is not present.
2. You can call EnvelopeViews: createRecipient from your server or from your browser app. If you call from your browser then you'll need to implement a private CORS gateway.
3. Either way, when the signer is ready to sign, you obtain the signing ceremony URL from the EnvelopeViews: createRecipient API call, then redirect the signer's browser to the URL.

> EnvelopeViews: createRecipient return an url that can be used once, why?

For security reasons. That's part of our information security architecture. And not only is the signing ceremony URL only usable once, it is also time limited. It should be used within a minute or two from when you receive it from DocuSign. It will expire 5 minutes after it was created.

> The second time I use this url I get 404 as response.

Yes, that's as designed. You get the URL, then you immediately redirect the signer to the URL. Then they sign. Then they're redirected back to your application.

If you want to provide a URL to a signer that the signer can use later on, you can implement that flow yourself. I've described how in other answers.

> So what I notice is the Recipient can't use the url (provided by the Sender) twice but he can't generate a new url every time because it isn't authenticated (no X-DocuSign-Authentication).
>
> How can I implement this flow properly?

You're almost there. Implement the JWT grant flow in your application. That way your app can impersonate the sender even when they're not around. When the signer wants to sign, your app gets the signing ceremony URL from DocuSign, and then redirects to enable signing.

An alternative which also works fine is for the sender to sign in to DocuSign by using the standard OAuth Authorization Code grant. This provides your app with an access token and a refresh token.

Your app enables the sender to send the enveloper by using the access token.

Later, when the signer wants to sign, your app uses the refresh token that it stored to generate a new access token. Use the access token with the EnvelopeViews: createRecipient API method to obtain the signing ceremony URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hope I understood...and I see two possible ways: **[1]** JWT grant flow on Sender side, retrieve the access token and send it to signers clients (they can use it later for `EnvelopeViews: createRecipient API`). **[2]** OAuth Authorization Code grant, same as 1 but sending the refresh token (instead access token) to signers clients. Did I get it right?

Comment: Close. In either case you need the access token. Also, you can get the signing ceremony URL from DocuSign via your server, if you wish. That way you won't need a private CORS proxy.

Comment: Ok, I prefer to get the signing ceremony URL via native rest calls in my clients. Thanks!